# Euler Systems and Coleman’s Conjecture

Tags: number-theory, algebraic-number-theory, elliptic-curves, class-field-theory, cyclotomic-fields

I’m trying to work on Coleman’s conjecture for abelian extensions of imaginary quadratic fields. I’ve read most papers by Seo regarding circular distributions. However, I’m a still confused about what it means that “all Euler systems come from cyclotomic units in an easy way”; what does this mean and what is that easy way?

Also, what is the extend to which similar thing can be done if the field Q of rationals is replaced by an imaginary quadratic field?

Comment: There are a few experts on Euler Systems on this site, but you'd probably be better off asking this on MathOverflow.

Comment: Thank you Mathsmo123